# How to migrate a very old Android app GCM->FCM, where app is both a sender and receiver

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Looking at the migration documentation, it looks like that is presupposing that my entire build environment (gradle, plugins, libraries) are up to date. In my case they are 5 years old, and I have no intention of upgrading any of them as I have absolutely no confidence that I will not end up in broken build hell. Additionally, this is an app which I will be replacing with a PWA later this year, so the migration doesn't need to be future-proof or use any new features.

So I'm looking for the minimal steps possible to migrate and keep the app from breaking. I think I have a handle on the receive side, but am looking for advice on registration and sending.

My current code is

```
// REGISTRATION
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    MyLog.d("[G152] about to register with gcm...");
    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
```

```
// SENDING
    final String API_KEY = "AIzaAt-kduR...xDass";
    URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
    StringEntity body = new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(gcMessage));
    httppost.setEntity(body);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

What are the minimal changes I need to make to migrate?

Answer (score 0):

There is an official migration guide for the client side: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

The new send API can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message